# Postgis funciton ST_Contains to write an sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am having some issues writing a query that uses the Postgis function st_contains. I want to display all the urban areas in the state of Colorado.  The actual definition of the query is here.

```
Return the names (name10) of all urban areas (in alphabetical order) that are entirely contained 
within Colorado. Return the results in alphabetical order. (64 records)
```

The tables that I am using are tl_2010_us_state10 (this stores information for the states). I think I am going to use the name10 variable in this table because that has all of the names of the states.

```
    Table "public.tl_2010_us_state10"
    Column   |            Type             |                            Modifiers                             
 ------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------
  gid        | integer                     | not null default 
  region10   | character varying(2)        | 
  division10 | character varying(2)        | 
  statefp10  | character varying(2)        | 
  statens10  | character varying(8)        | 
  geoid10    | character varying(2)        | 
  stusps10   | character varying(2)        | 
  name10     | character varying(100)      |
  lsad10     | character varying(2)        | 
  mtfcc10    | character varying(5)        | 
  funcstat10 | character varying(1)        | 
  aland10    | double precision            | 
  awater10   | double precision            | 
  intptlat10 | character varying(11)       | 
  intptlon10 | character varying(12)       | 
  coords     | geometry(MultiPolygon,4326) | 

 Indexes:
 "tl_2010_us_state10_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (gid)
 "tl_2010_us_state10_coords_gist" gist (coords)
```

Then I have a table that displays all the urban information. Once again I think I am going to use the name10 variable because it stores the name of all the urban areas.

```
                                      Table "public.tl_2010_us_uac10"
    Column   |            Type             |                           Modifiers                         
------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------
 gid        | integer                     | not null default 
 uace10     | character varying(5)        | 
 geoid10    | character varying(5)        | 
 name10     | character varying(100)      |
 namelsad10 | character varying(100)      | 
 lsad10     | character varying(2)        | 
 mtfcc10    | character varying(5)        | 
 uatyp10    | character varying(1)        | 
 funcstat10 | character varying(1)        | 
 aland10    | double precision            | 
 awater10   | double precision            | 
 intptlat10 | character varying(11)       | 
 intptlon10 | character varying(12)       | 
 coords     | geometry(MultiPolygon,4326) | 

 Indexes:
"tl_2010_us_uac10_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (gid)
"tl_2010_us_uac10_coords_gist" gist (coords)
```

The code that I wrote in my sql was

```
 select a.name10 as urban_area
from tl_2010_us_uac10 as a 
join tl_2010_us_state10 as b 
on ST_Contains(b.gid = a.gid)
where b.name10 = 'Colorado'
order by a.name10;
```

but I get this error

```
ERROR:  function st_contains(integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: ...010_us_uac10 as a join tl_2010_us_state10 as b on ST_Contain...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit 
type casts.
```

Comment: ST_Contains requires geometry columns but you are passing in gid which is an integer. It's also a function which requires two parameters but you have an equality statement. Try ST_Contains(b.coords, a.coords). http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html

Comment: Well thank you very much! I knew I was on the right track! If you create an actual answer I can select it as the right one and get you some points :)

Comment: have added as answer

Comment: Please do not repeat questions like this. I already explained in comments what was wrong with your previous, identical question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ST_Contains](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html) Requires two parameters, both of which should be of type geometry. Therefore you have made two mistakes.

1. Using int fields
2. Comparing them with = rather than supplying them as separate parameters

By correcting these you get

```
select a.name10 as urban_area
from tl_2010_us_uac10 as a 
join tl_2010_us_state10 as b 
  on ST_Contains(b.coords, a.coords)
where b.name10 = 'Colorado'
order by a.name10;
```

Comment: andy do you think you could help me with my other problem using st_touches? It's the last thing I need for my program to be complete

Comment: Heres the link if you have time to look at it, thanks again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870464/using-the-postgis-function-st-touches-to-write-a-sql-query